# How can I dynamically resize a DIV element's width to fit its text content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let say I have this HTML code snippet:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="textContent">Text Content Te</div>
<div id="anotherText">Another Text Content</div>
</div>
```

[Original HTML output http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1571/beforeeffect.gif](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1571/beforeeffect.gif)

I wonder how I could dynamically resize the `div`'s `textContent` width so that it fits its text content nicely (neither the text will be *wrapping* nor *scrolling* nor *truncated*).

[Desired HTML output http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/5851/desiredeffect.gif](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/5851/desiredeffect.gif)

I am open to any solution using CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want a div without any horizontal scroll bar??

Comment: floated elements will shrink-wrap if that's what you need, it's not clear what you mean by not wrapping, nor if you want to do this by CSS or JS.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the question to be more clear with what I want to achieve. No scrolling and I am open to CSS or JS solution (but I am glad to be surprise if it could be done via CSS fully).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I wonder how could I dynamically
>   resized the div's width to fit the
>   text content (without wrapping)?

Assuming the content would fit without overflowing, you could use a float without a width set (width isn't required in CSS 2.1 or greater). Without more detail, I can't suggest where to put it or what other properties to set to get the desired effect (eg, floats float down around following content, so put it at the beginning of a paragraph).

If you're not concerned with the effect looking perfect on old browsers like Internet Explorer, you could use `display: table` or `display: table-cell`, with the caveat that tables don't overflow: they stretch. That stretching may be desirable if you want to avoid overflow of your div, but allow it to overlow the viewport -- eg, a film strip that scrolls horizontally. In that case, altCognito's suggestion of `white-space: nowrap` would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks mate, I already edited the question to be more clear. Using table might be interesting... but I wonder if it is possible without using table element. Anyway, your answer is the most interesting answer so far. Thanks!

Comment: display: table has nothing to do with table elements beside the layout model.

Answer (score 6):

```
<style>
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

This will do the trick (though you probably should be more specific about the divs that you want to change. This means the divs that you do use this on won't have any line feeds unless you specify them yourself. But I'm guessing you're using this for labels, so you should be all set.

[See an example.](http://jsbin.com/axeku)